# Raster stack or brick unable to process trendmap function from greenbrown package

Tags: r, time-series, raster

The greenbrown package does not work with raster time series (RTS) and therefore I wanted to work with raster stack or brick. The trendmap function still does not work in this case with a length problem but both the stack and time function have the same amount of variables. The data is MODIS EVI.

it shows here http://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/trends.php

> trendmap <- TrendRaster(ndvimap, start=c(1982, 1), freq=12, method="AAT", breaks=1, funAnnual=max)

```
library(bfastSpatial)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(greenbrown)
library(rts)
library(lubridate)


#All file names
all_NDVI_files = c('MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_049.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_065.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_081.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_097.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_113.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_129.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_145.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_161.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_177.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_193.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_209.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_225.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_241.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_257.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_273.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_289.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_305.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_321.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_337.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2000_353.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_001.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_017.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_033.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_049.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_065.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_081.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_097.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_113.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_129.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_145.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_161.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_177.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_193.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_209.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_225.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_241.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_257.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_273.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_289.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_305.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_321.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_337.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2001_353.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2002_001.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2002_017.tif',
                   'MOD13Q1_EVI_2002_033.tif')

EVI_path <- //path
all_EVI <- list.files(EVI_path,
                      full.names = TRUE,
                      pattern = ".tif$")

EVI_stack <- stack(all_EVI)

EVI_Brick <- brick(EVI_stack)

ndvi.time = data.frame(year=substr(basename(all_NDVI_files),13,16),
                       julD=substr(basename(all_NDVI_files),18,20))
ndvi.time$dateJ = paste(ndvi.time$year,ndvi.time$julD,sep='-')
ndvi.time$julD = parse_date_time(ndvi.time$dateJ,'y-j')

trendmap <- TrendRaster(
     EVI_stack, start=min(ndvi.time$julD), freq=23, method='AAT', breaks=4)
```

The errors are

> trendmap <- TrendRaster(EVI_Brick, start=min(ndvi.time$julD), freq=23, method='AAT', breaks=4)
>   Error in Kendall(1:length(x), x) : length(x)<3
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In process[-(1:nh)] - process[1:(n - nh + 1)] :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   trendmap <- TrendRaster(EVI_stack, start=min(ndvi.time$julD), freq=23, method='AAT', breaks=4)
>   Error in Kendall(1:length(x), x) : length(x)<3
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
>     closing unused connection 4 (C:/Users/Test/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkbf9IT/raster/r_tmp_2019-11-07_040206_15796_57306.gri)
>   2: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
>     closing unused connection 3 (C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpkbf9IT\raster\r_tmp_2019-11-07_035713_15796_14107.gri)
>   3: In process[-(1:nh)] - process[1:(n - nh + 1)] :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

How can I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: I do not think that your `freq=23` argument is correct. This is supposed to be the collection frequency (eg., every 12 days) and not the number of observations. In looking at your data it appears to be 16 day collections.

Comment: According to http://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/man/TrendRaster.html
it says The frequency of observations. The default is 12 for monthly observations. Use 24 for bi-monthly observations, 365 for daily observations or 1 for annual observations. Therefore I opted for 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the size of the data. On a normal machine running the script for the entire study area led to issues but these were resolved by taking a small subset of the data.